# Dojo - Upload two files in one Form

Tags: upload, dojo

I use Dojo and want to send two files and one String to a REST Service. The HTML for that is the following:

```html
//...
<script>

dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");
dojo.require("dojox.embed.Flash");
if(dojox.embed.Flash.available){
  dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash");
}else{
  dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.IFrame");
}
</script>

//..
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/service" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" name="inputDataForm" id="inputDataForm">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="88" width="925">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Dataset1</td>
       <td><input name="train" type="file" value="Browse" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Uploader"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Dataset2</td>
       <td><input name="test" type="file" value="Browse" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Uploader"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Number of Customers</td>
       <td><input name="numberCustomers" size="40" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" /></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><input name="runButton" type="submit" value="Run" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="submitButton" /></p>  
    </form>
```

However: If I press the submit button, I can see via Firebug that there are sent TWO POST-Requests. One with the first file and the "Number of Customers" field and one with the second file and the "Number of Customers" field. However, my REST Service wants to have both files and the "Number of Customers" fields in one POST Request. How can i do that? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance
Natan

Comment: No wonder, that your form sends two requests. You are using two Uploader, each, based their functionality, have to send a POST request with file.

Comment: Did you try to use [FileList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/form/uploader/FileList.html) ?

Comment: I dont know how FileList can help me in this case. I would love to have two Browse buttons where two files can be choosen. After pressing the submit butto I would like to upload/send the files (and the other parts of the form) via POST to my Rest Service. Is this not possible when using dojo?